# MPIRUN is not executing on Worker node despite hostfile and SSH access

Tags: python, mpi, worker

I am executing simple demo code of `helloworld.py` on my main node with only one worker (VM) introduced in machinefile. I have installed mpirun on worker as well and also placed the script there (not sure where exactly to place it, /home/user/mpirun-master/demo).

MPI do check for ssh access to worker node before executing but it is only running on my main node and no process outcome come from the worker.

This is content of my machinefile

```
dell@172.16.197.1 # main node
kypo-1@172.16.197.129 # worker
```

And this is the output I am getting

```
mpirun -np 2 --machinefile machinefile python3 helloworld.py
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyHello, World! I am process 1 of 2 on dell-MS-7A70.
Hello, World! I am process 0 of 2 on dell-MS-7A70
```

Both are running on dell-MS-7A70 (main-machine device name), how can I make process to run on worker node. Is this problem arising due to worker machine being a virtual one?

Comment: the output is both interleaved and truncated, so it is hard to tell what is happening here.

Comment: Can you please explain it? I can give more info if required for clarity.

Comment: ideally you would have one line per MPI task. here there is only one 'on xxx' info, so it is just impossible to tell whether your job ran on one or two nodes.

Comment: How can I make sure?

Comment: my bad, i do not know what happened but I am sure I saw a truncated message (!)

Comment: First run `ssh kypo-1@172.16.197.129 hostname` to double check the hostname is correctly set. are you using Open MPI or MPICH? try `mpirun --machinefile machinefile python3 helloworld.py` (e.g. no `-np 2`) and see how many tasks are started and on how many nodes.

Comment: ssh is working fine.
However when I remove np, strangely it said, file not found
`python3: can't open file 'helloworld.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: is `helloworld.py` available on both nodes at the same path? since you are using two different accounts, that might not be true!

Comment: so I created another account on my worker node and have same name as main machine, make ssh connection, even then no process output from worker. path is: /home/dell/mpi4py-master/demo/helloworld.py

Comment: what if you invoke mpirun on one machine, and only have the other machine in your hostfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved when I created account with same name on my worker node and fixed slot numbers in machinefile for master and nodes as my script was preferring master eachtime.

Now my machinefile looks like:

```
172.16.197.129 max_slots=3 # worker 
172.16.197.1 max_slots=1 # master
```